# how to read terminal input in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I want to do some local node test before push the code to server.

how can I read terminal input as a input for my js script?
    readline or something

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to use third party library, if you just want to get command line params.

You can use `process.argv` property of `process` node core object.

just use `process.argv` & you are good to go.It returns an array in which by default there is 2 element, at 0 index Node execution directory & at 1 index working directory, so cmd line params start from 2nd index.

So in nutshell, you can access cmd line params using process.argv[2] onwards.

Answer (score 0):

For commandline app you can use `nicl`. you can make call to your chat module or websocket or whatever based on your logic.

```
var nicl = require("nicl");

function main() {
    nicl.printLine("Hello, what is your name?");
    var name = nicl.readLine();
    //call to websocket or any chat module 
    nicl.printLine("Great to meet you, " + name + "!");


    process.exit(0);
}

nicl.run(main);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! My problem is that I need to make a chat with terminal - input, feedback, feedback as further input as so on... how can I do that?